# visual studio 2010 c# traverse between web pages on aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

As title state after my solution on aspx.cs I want to switch to another web page to remove cookies and avoid resending the same email.

Comment: Refreshing the page causes the email to be resent. Solution I  [googled](http://www.mombu.com/php/php/t-send-mail-and-refresh-page-845566-last.html)

Comment: always try to include all those information in the question itself. Not in comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)**

After you done with your transaction, Redirect to another page (showing "It is done successfully" or some other message). Now Refresh can not beat you

To Redirect, You can use `Response.Redirect` method

```
 Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx")
```

Comment: What is the class or method required to redirect?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `Session` which prevents the email being sent again (if this is a once per session email (ie. Newsletter sign up etc)).

Then check whether this `Session` exists before sending the email:

```
if (Session["emailsent"]==null){

  //Send email code here

  Session["emailsent"] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to test 
in your page_load event

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//send mail...
}
else
{
//do nothing
}
```